# Internet Slow Ubuntu 20.4

Tags: internet

I am newbie in Ubuntu 20.4 and I am having some issues of poor internet speed. The issue normally starts when I open some streaming like Youtube or Udemy classes. It looks like that this streaming page is sucking all the internet speed and is impossible to open an additional webpage in the same time. It is also impossible to watch 2 videos on youtube on the same time.

My PC is a dual boot and in Windows the internet works fine.

Also, I have 2 wi-fi modens in my house and the problem is occurring in both.

I tried to change my browser from Firefox to Opera and the issue persisted.

However, I stay last month in my girlfriend house in an different city and the internet was working just fine. I suspect that is some configuration (DNS, MAC etc...).

Does anybody knows what can be the problem?

Comment: Just to confirm, the network speed *when using Ubuntu from a different city* was fine?

Comment: Yes, the internet from my girlfriend city works fine